# Loop and insert Id into the button

Tags: c#, webforms

My code:

```
<td style="width: 78%" class="alignLeft">            
        <% if(ReferenceFiles.Count > 0) {%>
        <% foreach (var file in ReferenceFiles) { %>
        <a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") + file %>">
            <% if(file.Contains("ModelingReport")) {%>
            ModelingReport
            <%} %></a>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDeleteModelingReport" runat="server" OnClick="DeleteModelingReport" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"  CausesValidation="False" /><br />
        <% } %>
        <%}
           else
           {%>
               <label>No references uploaded.</label>
           <% } %>
    </td>
```

I'm looping through the collection of files and printing each file on the page with the delete button next to it. But the problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to pass the name of the file to the button so that when button is clicked, in the event handler function I can delete that file.

I've tried doing

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="<%= file %>"
```

But it did not work, the "file" which is a string name of the file is not being set to the Id of the button.
Thanks.